# Syntax for arithmetics on prior distributions in JAGS/BUGS

Tags: winbugs, jags

For a prior on a bound measure, I am trying to stretch a beta distribution between [-1,1], "[a]s described by Barnard, McCulloch & Meng (2000)" (according to [this tutorial](http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2014/03/bayesian-first-aid-pearson-correlation-test/)).

Specifically, I am trying to implement this suggestion:

```
rho_half_with ~ dbeta(1, 1)
# shifting and streching rho_half_with from [0,1] to [-1,1]
rho ~ 2 * rho_half_with - 1
```

However, I always get

```
syntax error on line (...) near "2"
```

No entry in the manual for [JAGS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/Manuals/) or BUGS I found deals with manipulations of distributions (as sources of stochastic relation assignments). Is it indeed possible to apply basic arithmetic operations to BUGS/JAGS stochastic relation (following the `~` operator), and if yes, how?

Comment: What happens if you switch "~" to "<-" in the last line? ~ is used for "stochastic" relations while <- is used for "equality" relations.

Comment: @Rasmus Bååth: no :( ...

Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
   Graph Size: 48

Deleting model

Error in setParameters(init.values[[i]], i) : Error in node rho
Attempt to set value of non-variable node

Comment: I believe that error is not related to the code in the question. The "syntax error on line (...) near "2"" part should be due to the use of ~ instead of <-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code you have posted is that you use a `~` in a non-stochastic relation, where JAGS would want you to use `<-` instead. The following should work:

```
rho_half_with ~ dbeta(1, 1)
# shifting and streching rho_half_with from [0,1] to [-1,1]
rho <- 2 * rho_half_with - 1
```

Regarding the error message you mention in the comments you get that because you try to initiate a variable that is not stochastic (`rho`). Remove that initialization or switch to initializing `rho_half_with` to solve that problem.